# Javascript regex to detect http://www.google.fr

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm new at using Javascript regexp and after several failed attempts I'm still wondering how to check if an URL starts with http://www.google.fr

Comment: Dis question came infinet time....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var url = "http://www.google.fr";
if(url.match(/^http:\/\/www\.google\.fr/))
    alert("It matches!");
```

But you might want to allow more variations of the address, and it's also important to check that what follows it is something valid, so you don't match things like `http://www.google.fr-h4xx0r.com`

Eg: `/^http:\/\/(?:www\.)?google\.fr(?=\/|$)/i`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var url_reg         = /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/;
```